# Laravel: Filtering by empty relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 models:

- User.php
- Shift.php
- ShiftRequest.php

A user can have many Shifts. A shift can have many ShiftRequests. I am trying to retrieve all shifts that have no shift requests with eager loading. Here's what I've got:

User.php

```
public function shiftsBetween($startDate, $endDate, $with = ['shiftType'], $withoutShiftRequests = false)
{
    $q = $this->hasMany(Shift::class)
        ->between($startDate, $endDate)
        ->with($with);

    if ($withoutShiftRequests) {
        // $q->has('request');
    }
    return $q->get();
}
```

If I add `->has('request')`, it'll get me all shifts that have a shift request. Is there an opposite function of that (such as `notHas('request')`)?

I've also considered putting a constraint in the `$with` array but because it's a one to many relationship, there's nothing in the shift_request table to constrain it to.

Comment: I'm a Larvel person, but maybe this will help: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#unions

Comment: @MEmerson Thanks for the reply. `request` is not a column (it's a model relationship function) and the shifts table does't have any shift_request_id because it's a one to many relationship, so I'm afraid your suggestion won't work in this case... Unless I'm missing something

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer myself:
https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/QueriesRelationships.html#method_doesntHave

`->doesntHave()` is the opposite of `->has()` - makes sense :)